# SQL Backup Operation has detected an unexpected file in a FILESTREAM container, what should I do?

Tags: backup, filestream

`BACKUP DATABASE [DB] TO  DISK = N C:\Program File...` failed with the following error:

> The backup operation has detected an unexpected file in a FILESTREAM
> container. The backup operation will continue and include file
> C:\FSFfta\Fsa.vbs

I get the above error daily on the backup maintenance scheduled job - what do I need to do to resolve this? (I didn't get an error when backed up manually). How can I check what is the state of the backup, and whether it can be restored?

Comment: Can you include which DB and version that you are using

Comment: The only way to know for sure if a backup can be restored is to restore it... I would _guess_ you're fine, but I've never experienced that error before. It seems like a descriptive enough error though...